# How do you read an R dataset with same name but from different packages?

Tags: r, data-import

I'm currently taking this R course on DataCamp ("Quantitative Risk Management in R") where there are two datasets with the same name but contain different values. They're both named "DJ" (Dow Jones stock prices), but one contains the values from 1991 to 2000, and the other from 1985-2015. I need to use these two datasets at different points of the course, so how can I separately load them into my workspace? So far, what I've done to load them is use:

```
data("DJ")
```

**EDIT:** As a response to MrFlick's comment, the first dataset is from the `QRM` package, and the second one is from the `qrmdata` package. Sorry for not including this in the original post.

Comment: Are they from the same package?

Comment: It's not clear how the same package can hold two datasets with the same name but different data. What package are these data sets supposed to be coming from? Can you provide any specific details?

Comment: `DJ1991 <- get(data('DJ'package = 'give the package name'))` same as `DJ1985` then you have two different datsets

Comment: @MrFlick The first dataset is from the `QRM` package, and the second one is from the `qrmdata` package.